# Adding user management for our container via dockerfile

Tags: docker, authentication

We're using docker for our project. We've a monitoring service (for our native application) which is running on Docker.

Currently there is no user management for this monitoring service. Is there any way we can add user management from Dockerfile?

Please note that I'm not looking docker container user management.

In simple words functionality that I'm looking for is:

1. Add any user and password in dockerfile.
2. While accessing external IP, same user and password must be provided to view running monitoring service.

Answer (score 0):

From your few information about your setup, I would say the authentification should be handled by your monitoring service. If this was a kind of webapp you could use a simple basic auth as a first step.

Answer (score 0):

Docker doesn't know what's running in your container, and its networking setup is limited to a simple pass-through between containers or from host ports to containers.  It's typical to run programs with many different network protocols in Docker (Web servers, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Redis all have different wire protocols) and there's no way Docker on its own could inject an authorization step.

Many non-trivial Docker setups include some sort of HTTP reverse proxy container (frequently Nginx, occasionally Apache) that can both serve a Javascript UI's built static files and also route HTTP requests to a backend service.  You can add an authentication control there.  The mechanics of doing this would be specific to your choice of proxy server.

Consider that any information you include in the `Dockerfile` or `docker build --args` options can be easily retrieved by anyone who has your image (looking at its `docker history`, or `docker run` a debug shell on it).  You may need to inject the credentials at run time using a bind mount if you think they're sensitive and you're not storing your image somewhere with strong protections (if anyone can `docker pull` it from Docker Hub).